# Draw ArcCtg ( x ) plot

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I don't get it how to draw the graph for the function: y = arcctg( x ).. I'm not so good at math but that's what I've done so far:

```
void drawgraph()
{
    double x,y,z;
    float xmin=0, xmax=M_PI, ymin=0, ymax=M_PI;
//  glPushMatrix();
    glBegin (GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
for (x = xmin; x <= xmax; x+=0.1)
{
    for (y = ymin; y <= ymax; y+=0.1)
    {
        y = atan(x);
    y = M_PI_2 -y;  //that will transform from arctan( x ) to  actan (x ) I guess..
        glVertex3f (x, y, -1);
    }
}
glEnd ();
//glPopMatrix();
}
```

when I run the program It's not responding : - (... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: not responding to what? There is no input there!

Comment: no, it's not responding at all! just white screen! in task menager: Not Responding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the following:

```
for (y = ymin; y <= ymax; y+=0.1)
    {
        y = something;
    }
```

This will create an endless loop (unless `something > ymax`, which it is not in your case).
Imagine the following:

```
for (a = 0; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        a = 5;
    }
```

Use another variable inside your loop instead of y, and you'll be fine.

Comment: how could I be so stupid ))) lol's. Thanks...no it run's but there is no Graph ((

Comment: No problem, we all have it from time to time. Afraid I can't help you with OpenGL though.

Comment: That does not matter's becose this is just like LineTo in winAPI or line in TurboPascal... the problem is in for loop ...